# What's the word for a person who can read lines on a forehead?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, professions

Is there a word for a person who can read lines on a forehead?

In India, some people can read forehead lines and claim to tell you your future.

Comment: Is the word the same _as what_?

Comment: How about *foreheadcaster*, *forehead teller", or *progcreasticator*? ;-)

Comment: A *brow-knowser?*

Comment: Or a *headliner*.  Or a reader between the headlines.

Comment: @Robusto I'm asking you as the highest reputation close-voter in the list, what part of the question is unclear? I would expect the second and fifth highest reputation holders in this site to be able to understand a simple question like _"Is the there any word same for person who can read lines on forehead"_ despite it's unusual phrasing. I don't know if it was close-voted before or after Mari-LouA's edit but surely it's quite clear now and can be reopened.

Comment: @Frank When the question was closed (or at least when I close-voted), it asked if the word for a head-line-reader was the same, not whether it exists. That is very unclear to me—as I said in my initial comment, same as what?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I can now see that the question was closed/held 20:36 and then edited at 23:37 by Mari-LouA, prior to that it was just the stupid _two hours ago_ etc that didn't let me see precisely when the edit was made. Wouldn't this have gone back into the review queue and then those that closed should see the edit and vote to reopen. The question is pretty clear now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The skill is called **[metopomancy](http://wordinfo.info/unit/1304)**.

The practitioner is a  **metoposcopist**.

Comment: According to the link (which I found) the person versed in this "art" is a "metoposcopist". You might want to edit your answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I think a metoscopist is a practitioner of metoposcopy, which is determining someone's character by from the lines on the forehead rather than of metopomancy, which involved divining the future by reading such lines. I think metopomancer is the appropriate word for a practitioner of metopmancy.

Comment: A subspecialization of Phrenology? https://www.google.com/search?q=phrenology&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb